# Unexplainable behavior in C. Odd vs Even number of strings

Tags: c, string, network-programming

So I have a problem that I can not figure out. I am writing some code in C. I kept winding up with issues where reading from the network would seemly randomly work.

I finally traced it down to the number of strings in the code. I cant believe it but I have verified it pretty in depth.

The code base is rather massive so I am not sure of the overall number of strings parity. However I know that if i add an odd number then the program works, and if i add an even number it doesnt.

Just to clarify when I say it doesnt work, It does still build and execute, but everytime I try to read anything over the network all i get is 0's. When its working I get the correct data.

has anyone ever heard of anything like this? Or have any idea what could be causing this? I could see if the data portion of the program was getting too large and starting to impede on other code's space but the fact that its an odd/even thing completely confuses me.

thanks

EDIT (Adding more info):

The platform is a custom designed device. the code base is redboot but its been altered significantly for the custom device.

snipped for example:

//This will work because its an odd number of strings.

```
char* str1 = "test";
char* str2 = "test2";
char* str3 = "test3";

int i = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + strlen(str3);
```

......................................

if i were to change the last line to

```
int i = strlen(str1) + str(len2);
```

so that str3 gets optimized out by the compiler then the code will no longer work. I have tested this many times with various lenghts of strings all result in the same odd/even behavior.  (i is just sent to a debug log so that its not optimized out. nothing fancy is done with it).

Edit2:  The above code can be placed anywhere in the codebase and it causes the same problem. It doesnt matter if its been executed or not, which leads me to believe its not a stack overflow.

Comment: It's likely some error in your code, not the number of lines. You should add plenty of logging and localize the problem, then (if you still need that) ask a detailed question here.

Comment: Please post a short yet compilable snipper piece of code that illustrate the problem. Narrowing the problem down could event help you see that solution.

Comment: Agreed.  This posted needs to isolate the problem.

Comment: You don't say anything about what platform you're on? If you're on a desktop system, the number or "oddness" of your strings shound have nothing to say. If you're on some more limited embedded system, that may be another issue. Most likely it's as sharptooth points out, a problem with the code.

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "number of strings"? you mean the number of string literals into the source code (like `char *s = "hello"`)? And how do you verified it pretty in depth this?

Comment: your EDIT: what are you doing with "i"? I am convinced, that it may be a buffer overflow, that has nothing to do with str1 to str3, they only move the problem.

Comment: Should those subsequent `str(lenX)` occurrences be `strlen(strX)` ?

Comment: your statement about moving the code around is ambiguous. What happens if you put the string definitions in file scope? Also you didn't answer the second question that I asked in my reply.

Comment: Try `int i = 0; i += strlen(str1); i += strlen(str2); i += strlen(str3);` and stuff like that to see how it changes it. Alternatively, declare the variables you're assigning the string literals to as `const char *` rather than just `char *` (no clue if that would make any difference, but the fact that it doesn't matter whether or not the code is actually executed makes me wonder if it could be a compile-time/compiler problem that doesn't manifest until later). Also, have you tried using OTHER numbers of strings, like 4 and 5, 6 and 7, etc?

Comment: After two hours and two edits, there still isn't anywhere near enough information to make more than a wild guess at the problem.  Voting to close.

Comment: David what more information can i provide? The code base is redboot which imakes it HUGE. I've answerd all questions people ask. I realize its a long shot but I was hoping maybe somehow someone has seen a problem like this before.  In reply to JAB yes i have tried up to 15 strings total (using all numbers below that) and it is always the same. odd works, even doesnt.

Comment: Check if `strlen` is being overridden by a macro of some sort, and also check if `stdio.h` is `#include`d in the code files, just in case.

Comment: @Without me Its just Aweso: no you still didn't answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guess.

Assume the platform is 32 bit.

Perhaps the compiler aligns some of the data structutres of your program in memory on eight byte boundaries.  You have a whole load of string pointers in your data segment and maybe some other stuff too.  If there is an odd number of strings, the next thing that needs an eight byte alignment has four bytes of padding in front of it.  If there is an even number of strings, there is no padding.

Whatever piece of data that is just before that eight byte aligned object has an overflow bug that just destroys the contents of between one and four bytes after it.  If there is padding after this thing, nothing bad happens.  If there is no padding, the eight byte aligned object gets zapped.

Answer (score 6):

Random stab-in-the-dark time...

A common misunderstanding when reading from network sockets is that a `read()` of 10 bytes will return the next 10 bytes. It won't. It will return UP TO 10 bytes, and you may need to call `read()` multiple times to get all the data you require.

Answer (score 4):

I've not heard of a problem like this before.  You sound like you're very frustrated and you say that your code base is rather massive.  If solving the problem is important, I would suggest that you try to reproduce the issue with a smaller amount of code.  It may also help you get answers here if you post some samples of your code to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 4):

Where do you take the assertion from that it has to do with the parity of the number of strings? If I try to interpret what you say carefully, this tells me that small changes in code let you trigger unexpected behavior.

Smells like stack overflow. Do you allocate large arrays or strings on the stack and then do `read` and `write` to them?
In that case try to allocate/deallocate these large buffers dynamically through `malloc/free`.

Comment: i wantet to post the same answer. it is called a Heisenberg-Bug: add more debug code and the error moves to another point in the program.

Comment: Peter: Not a "Heisenberg-Bug", but a "Heisenbug".

Answer (score 1):

if you have somthing like

```
char buf[10];
long var;
strcpy(buf, "ganz viel text");
```

you may or may not get an segmentation violation or strange behaviour with variable "var". if you put more debug text into your code, the linker may reallocate the variables, or the compiler may do other code optimization, and reallocation space allocation in memory.